# How to remove pipeline authorization from a service connection?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've created a new Service Connection in an Azure DevOps Project.  During creation I unchecked the "Allow all pipelines to use this service connection" option.  Under Project Settings | Service Connections |  | Policies it shows all the existing (YAML) pipelines under "Authorized Pipelines".  I only want one of the pipelines to be authorized - how can I remove authorization from the other pipeline?  I can't see anything relevant in the UI.

Comment: This appears to be partly a UI bug.  When I tried to run the pipeline I _did_ want to have access I had to grant access.  The "Authorized Pipelines" area then updated to show only the one I just granted to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go user profile, and enable new feature of **New service connections experience**:

[image]

We expand the feature removing authorized Pipelines with the new feature of service connection experience.

[image]

As you can see there has an icon [image] can let you revoke the pipeline's access.

**Note**: Since this is a new feature which provided recently. There will be no pipeline listed there after you enable the new service connection experience. Just refresh the page several times, it will displayed.